# French version of "famous last words"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

There's an English saying, *famous last words*, and is usually said in response to an unlikely claim or suggestion, as if to imply that these will be the speaker's last words before an untimely death.

> Person 1: Let's take a ride on the roller coast in this old abandoned theme park! I'm sure it will be fine...
>   Person 2: Famous last words.

Comment: It's almost like asking for the translation of a meme. I don't remember any that crossed language boundaries. I could be wrong, but I don't think that answering this question in the way you expect is possible.

Comment: You mean that there is no French saying with the same meaning?

Comment: Well, if you want the same literal “meaning” you could go for “on en connaît d'autres qui sont morts peu de temps après avoir dit ça”… but nobody will react to that the way you want. You're dealing with something I would call a "situational idiom" which "means" nothing and only has a relational/social effect.

Comment: I agree, this is hard to translate, but saying it "means" nothing is not correct. It is one of those clever little quips that english is so good at and where french feels too verbose. I would venture "On y crois!" which conveys the wishful thinking taking place or even "Belle épitaphe!" for the potential imminent death.

Comment: Yes, from the responses, it appears nobody is actually familiar with this expression, or does not properly understand its usage. My explanation was flimsy but I was not counting on people needing it. I just tweaked it to be a bit more accurate, for what it's worth.

Comment: I tweaked my previous comment (yes diamond-magic). But I'm still convinced that this expression can be explained only through context. If you ask me, in this context I would answer in French “Maaaais oui”, which "means" yes just as much as the pretended "famous last words" are "meant" famous.

Comment: Is there a liaison on "mais oui"? I assume not.

Comment: No, "oui" is reluctant to that. However its homonym "ouïe" is less capricious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'expression équivalente qui serait reconnue comme un idiome. Pour rendre « *Famous last words!* » comme interjection signifiant que l'on pense que l'interlocuteur s'apprête à faire quelque chose de plus dangereux qu'il ne le croit, en gardant la même connotation, on peut dire

> On écrira ça sur ta tombe.

[Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?query=%22famous+last+words%22&moreResults=1&source=english) ne trouve qu'un exemple, ce qui n'est pas surprenant puisque l'expression est familière, peu susceptible d'apparaître dans les textes que Linguee indexe.

> j'ai l'impression de prononcer des paroles qui seront gravées dans le marbre.

Sur [Word Reference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=172688), [edwingill](http://forum.wordreference.com/member.php?u=27168) propose

> C'est ce que tu crois.

qui peut convenir, mais est beaucoup plus générique : cette expression n'est pas limitée à un danger ou à de l'optimisme mal placé.

[zam](http://forum.wordreference.com/member.php?u=29611) propose

> Ça, je te le ressortirai !
>   On en reparlera !
>   Oui, bon, ça je le note hein !

qui préparent le locuteur à dire « je te l'avais bien dit ».

[Quantz](http://forum.wordreference.com/member.php?u=144511) propose

> Propos téméraires

qui existe également sous la forme « propos bien téméraires » et qui me plaît bien. C'est moins fort que l'expression anglaise (pour le coup, l'anglais fait de l'hyperbole alors que le français tend à l'euphémisme), mais la connotation est la même. On peut parler de « propos (bien) téméraires » sans problème au discours indirect :

> En dépit de ces propos bien téméraires, la rupture apparaît inévitable.   ([Sabrina Jacquel](http://docnum.univ-lorraine.fr/public/NANCY2/doc78/2003NAN21005_1.pdf))

De manière moins imagée, on peut dire

> Tu risques de regretter ces paroles.
>   Je sens que je vais regretter ces paroles.

Avec moins de connotation de danger, on peut dire

> Soyons optimistes…

qui implique un doute (par valeur d'antiphrase), mais de façon moins marquée que l'expression anglaise.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand Gilles wins. Merci. I was surprised how many people are not familiar with this particular English expression, it's so very common! Goes to show how little I know. Lucky you're around.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel's suggestion of  "*Belle épitaphe !*" comes closest, IMO. It is echoed by the first suggestion here: *On écrira ça sur ta tombe.*

Answer (score 2):

Laure's answer covered the « It's hard to believe » aspect pretty well, but in a situation like your example, I think I would rather emphasize the « You'll probably die if you try this » aspect.

However, I can't think of any idiomatic expression with this precise meaning. In such situation, I often answer with something like

> Attends, j'appelle une ambulance.

Implicitly meaning « if you try this, you'll probably hurt yourself very badly, and I'll probably be saving your life by calling an ambulance in advance ».

Answer (score -1):

Il est souvent question du *mot de la fin* :

> Le célèbre mot de la fin.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ces mots: "Il est souvent question de..."

In this context it doesn't seem to make sense. "It is often a question of...." ?

Comment: Quel rapport avec quelque chose difficile à croire ?

Comment: @Aerovistae *Être question de* is a phrase. It means something like "we usually talk about".

Comment: @Aerovistae Kareen à bien donné le sens de la phrase qui vous interpelle. C'est une tournure, une formule qui sous entend : « [lorsque que l'on utilise *last words* dans le contexte cité,] il est souvent *traduit* par ... »; dans ce sens, *question* est un mot qui peut être synonyme de *traduit*, *d'interprété* ou de tout autre mot qui éclaire et renvoie à la *question posée*. Je n'ai pas trouvé de meilleur traduction que celle proposée, et le logiciel impose des réponses de plus de 30 caractères, d'où ces quelques mots mis en introduction.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - J'ai fait référence à la dernière partie de l'introduction ; le *mot de la fin* termine la conversation, le spectacle ou la vie d'un humain, que l'on y croit ou non.